# how to update a specific [KEY] : [VALUE] of Array of object stored as State variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state varible named returnValuesArr.
[image: this is picture of console for this state variable, as you can see it is an array of objects]

Now i want to update 'Value' key of the first object after making an API call.
I tried this.

```
const getReturns = async () => {
        const res1 = await axios.get(`${BASE_URLS.signupBaseUrl}/mutual-funds/nav/${filteredList.data[0].quandl_code}`).catch(err => {throw err})
        setReturnValueArr({...returnValuesArr, returnValuesArr:  {...returnValuesArr.find(item => item.code === res1.data.data.dataset.dataset_code), [value] : res1.data.data.returns }})

        return;
    }
```

but it shows no effect on my state variable..it is same as before.
Can anyone please help what i am doing wrong. or is there any syntactical mistake

Comment: what is the name of your state variable?

Comment: returnValuesArr

Comment: is that state variable an object or an array?

Comment: it's an array of objects, you can refer to the console image i have shared above

Comment: So the first mistake I found here is, setReturnValueArry should take argument an array but you're passing an object.

Comment: For simplicity, I would suggest, take the state array into a temp variable, update that variable, log that variable to check if the value is correctly updated, and then pass that updated temp variable into state setter function.

Comment: BTW you shouldn't just take your company's data SS and paste here, you could've just took a sample data with a couple of entries.